# There seems to be a bias against states with more 1s, in IBM's calibration matrix generator: What are the consequences and possible solutions?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, measurement, noise, error-mitigation

Qiskit's function `CompleteMeasFitter` builds a calibration matrix in this way (2 qubit case):

- Everything is initialized in the state $|00\rangle$, which is the usual case for IBM hardware.
- For $|00\rangle$, it just measures the proportion of counts for $|00\rangle, |01\rangle, |10\rangle, |11\rangle$.
- For $|01\rangle$, it applies an $X$ gate to the second qubit, then measures the counts for all 4 states.
- For $|10\rangle$, it applies an $X$ gate to the first qubit, then measures the counts for all 4 states.
- For $|11\rangle$, it applies an $X$ gate to both qubits, then measures the counts for all 4 states.

In the $|00\rangle$ case the calibration matrix is picking up the ***measurement error***.
In all other cases, the calibration matrix is picking up measurement error ***plus some gate error***.
For states involving more 1s, the calibration matrix elements are ***less pure*** (there's more errors).

- Is there a ***consequence*** of this? E.g. the $|00\rangle$ counts will be corrected better than the others?
- Is there any way to mitigate this bias?

Comment: Great question! My understanding is that single-qubit gates have a much higher fidelity than the measurement process, so the errors due to the X-gate shouldn't have a big effect on the calibration matrix. But I guess that approaches where you characterize both gate and measurement errors (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.09188) should give a more accurate calibration matrix (that could be something interesting to look at)